# define assignment operator= that allows only zero rhs, otherwise won't compile

Tags: c++

In short:
How do I define operator= for my class such that it compiles only if rhs is 0 (obj = 0)
but gives compilation error if rhs is non-0 value.
I know it is possible, forgot how.

Longer:
I have class C. I want to allow assignment obj = 0 for object of this class (which means, reset the object), but assignment from no other integer or pointer is defined. No conversion from integer or from pointer is defined other than obj=0.

```
C obj;
obj = 0; // reset object
```

Inside the `operator=`, I can do `assert(rhs == 0)`, but that's not good enough.
I know it is possible 
to define `operator=` such that
it gives compilation error if rhs is not 0. Forgot details.
Can anybody refill ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would anyone want to do that? If it resets the object, write a method called `reset`. Or is it your intention to confuse whoever is trying to read your code?

Comment: @Axel: '=0' operation is common for smart pointers. And for classes that behave like ID of some kind. By analogy with regular pointers, on wihch =0 is "overloaded with reset". So for ID-like and SmartPointer classes, this is well established practice I'd say. OTOH, is you have 150 classes, each has "reset" method, how is this better than =0, when you need need to track which exactly reset() is called in a particular p->reset() call ? Don't see much difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a *pointer-to-member*:

```
class foo
{
    // Give it a meaningful name so that the error message is nice
    struct rhs_must_be_zero {};

    // The default operator= will still exist. If you want to
    // disable it as well, make it private (and the copy constructor as well
    // while we're at it).

    foo(const foo&);
    void operator=(const foo&); 

public:
    foo& operator=(int rhs_must_be_zero::*) { return *this; }
};
```

Since you can't access `foo::rhs_must_be_zero`, you cannot name a pointer to member from this class. The only pointer to member you can name is the null pointer, aka the literal zero.

Demo at http://ideone.com/bT02z

Comment: but example compiles on `foo f, g; f = g`. It seems you also should make `foo& operator=(const foo &)` private.

Comment: @Lol4t0: this was not required by the OP. I update the answer anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Lol4t0: f =  g is fine if g is of same type. f = 1 must be disallowed, f = n (where n is int != 0)must be disallowed. I did  not say any assignment shall be disallowed. I said that if rhs is integer, then it shall compile if it's 0 and not compile if it is not 0.

Comment: @Andrei: so this will work as asked (provided you don't have a non-`explicit` constructor which takes an `int`).

Comment: isn't there also solution where rhs type is some templated partially defined type ?